# How does the mobile security technology APNS and 3LM work?

Tags: mobile, corporate-policy, password-policy

[APNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Push_Notification_Service) is an iPhone technology that assists with mobile push.   [3LM](http://www.3lm.com/) is a BIOS-level security technology embedded in certain Android phones.

I recently got off the phone with Boxtone and they said they leverage those technologies to enforce corporate policy (password length, remote wipe) to each device.  I'm right now weeding through the sales pitch and am trying to get solid technical answers.  Other products that might be comparable include [MobileIron](http://www.mobileiron.com/), [Zenprise](http://www.zenprise.com/), and [Airwatch](http://www.air-watch.com/?gclid=CMSr94rrw6sCFcjc4AodPgS63w).

- How does 3LM and APNS work to achieve policy compliance?
- What are the benefits/limitations of these technologies?
- How can I use them as an administrator/non-programmer?
- How can I use them as a developer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APNS is a way of pushing updates from third party application servers to the iOS devices. It has nothing to do with the security. Apple believes that it saves battery life having push technology over traditional background processes(pull technology).

3LM is a MDM (Mobile Device Management) software. With the emergence of Bring Your Own Device (BYOD) initiative in the corporate world, the employee's phones and tablets must be protected by malware. These technologies maintain a whitelist approach (sometimes also a blacklist) meaning only the above mentioned softwares can be installed by the employee from the Android Market.

In some worst cases, corporation will have their own Market or AppStore and employees can download apps available on those appStore.

p.s: You cannnot play Angry Birds :(

Comment: Thanks for joining Security.SE!  Interesting thing about the app store.. I asked about it here: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/15033/396